# How to Configure a Filepath for a Maven or Spring Resource

Tags: spring, file, maven, resources, download

I have always been horrible at knowing filepaths. :(

I have the following setup in a Maven-Spring application

```
src/main/java
    com.mycompany.controller
        MyController.java
src/main/resources/downloads
    MyDocument.docx
```

I am trying to access my document in the controller.

```
String filepath = "";
File file = new File(filepath);
```

I've tried a number of paths, but can't seem to get it passed a `FileNotFound` error. I would think the path should be `/src/resources/downloads/MyDocument.docx`, but that's not working. I've tried absolute and relative paths, but can't seem to get it working.

I am not sure if I need to fix the path or maybe move where my documents are located. Anyone know? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `MyController`:

```
InputStream resource = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/downloads/MyDocument.docx");
```

This should work if the resource is placed in the `downloads` package.

Comment: Why complicate things with a relative path? Why not just `/downloads/MyDocument.docx`?

Comment: It seemed to get past the `FileNotFound`, but after the call, the `resource` variable is null. Maybe this method just doesn't throw an exception when it can't find the file?

Comment: It just returns null if the resource was not found. Make sure that `src/main/resources` is actually a source directory, and it's packaged together with `src/main/java` when you compile your project.

Comment: I did try `src/main/resources/downloads/MyDocument.docx` and it worked. What all is involved in making a folder a source folder? I know how to do it in Eclipse ("Use as source folder"), but will that export when I build the WAR?

Comment: I haven't been using Eclipse for years now, but chances are that it filters resources when assembling the .war (which means that in only copies e.g. *.xml/*.properties/etc. files, but probably not a .docx)